# Re-Using a cell in Excel doc as a parameter to a custom query

Tags: sql, excel

I am using a custom Excel query to get results from a database.

My goal is to make it easier for Excel users in the database to run custom queries. For that I am throwing in a bunch of filters.

The problem comes in when i have more then 12 '?' parameters.

Is it possible for me to specify the exact cell, or maybe reuse a parameter (ie something like
here is a sql example of what I mean:

```
SELECT * From table
WHERE table.start_date > ?
      AND table.end_date < ?
```

**Both** ? marks refer to the the same date that is stored in 'A1' cell.

As it is right now, when I save, I have to specify 2 different parameters and point them to that cell.

What I want is to tell Excel that it's the same parameter and only have to specify it once.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: ` where x>a or x<a ` is the same as ` where x!=a `

Comment: My question isn't about the specific comparisons. I need to know if there's a way for me to specify a parameter once in a query and then re-use it again in the query.

Comment: If you want a more generic approach then you're going to need to provide more details: what database are you using, and exactly how are you constructing and running your queries? If the sample "as is" SQL you provided is not representative, then can you provide one which is?

Comment: Added some clarification in my question, hope it helps

Comment: You didn't really add any extra information in your update.  What database (Access/Oracle/SQL server/MySQL/etc) ? - it usually makes some difference.  And exactly how is that SQL you show being generated?  And what exactly is the 'problem' you mention which occurs when you have >12 parameters?  Do you get an error message, does the query just fail, or what?

Comment: My question isn't about the query (or what db it connects to). The way Excel lets me specify parameters from a cell is if in Command Text of Connection Properties I specify a '?' instead of a value. After I press 'OK' I get a popup to select a cell for the parameter. Something like 'Select a cell to use for Parameter1'. I choose a cell, and it runs the query. I want to use that Parameter1 in multiple places

Comment: I want to be able to do something like table.start_date > Sheet3.Cell('J1') instead of just ?

Comment: All I can suggest is you use ADO, and build and execute the query SQL "manually" in VBA.

Comment: Ahh I was afraid of that (haven't touched vb script yet)